# Is there an API to get Indian pincodes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an application in which I need get pincodes (India) of the users and get the city and the state details. I have not found an effective way to do this other than **scrape** the internet for pincodes which is quite cumbersome and time consuming.

Is there any API available for this purpose?

P.S. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Indian Pincodes API](https://www.indianpincodes.co.in/). I built this for one of our projects. It's simple and you do not need any authentication.

https://www.indianpincodes.co.in/

Comment: Thank you very much.